# Is there some kind of static class that contains my application's window information in WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms

Is there an easy way in a winforms application to get access to the collection of forms that are open and which ones are on top, order they opened, etc.?

I'd like to make it a static class so I can call it anywhere in my code without having to pass objects around.

Otherwise, I'll have to make my own "window manager" so to speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a collection containing all of the forms that are currently open in your application using the **[`Application.OpenForms` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx)**. This is indeed a static property, so it's available anywhere.

However, I'm not sure that this meets your requirements of indicating the order in which the forms were opened. You're going to have to keep track of this information yourself.

Note that the collection returned by `OpenForms` also does not track which thread opened each form. If you want to access members of the form, you should check its [`InvokeRequired` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx) first to prevent receiving an `InvalidOperationException` exception.

Comment: I ended up making my own. It uses a linked list to keep track of the order. I move items to the top of the linked list on the form.activate event and remove on the formclose event. Works well enough. I've been able to use the order to spawn new forms cascaded relative to the form that spawned it.